# How do I draw a text-based graph of a given function f(x)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, if-statement, graph

I am tackling a university computer science assignment. I am only a couple of months into learning python programming.
Here is the objective in my assignment:

> Write a program to draw a text-based graph of a mathematical function f(x). Use axis limits of -10 to 10 and only plot discrete points, i.e. points with integer value ordinates.
>
> Sample I/O:

```
Enter a function f(x):
x+2
          |       o
          |      o
          |     o
          |    o
          |   o
          |  o
          | o
          |o
          o
         o|
--------o-+----------
       o  |
      o   |
     o    |
    o     |
   o      |
  o       |
 o        |
o         |
          |
          |
```

So far, I have managed to create the area of the graph and the axes using nested `for` loops. Here is my code at the moment (I have commented out unnecessary or incomplete lines):

```
import math

#f = input("Enter a function f(x):\n")

for row in range (0, 21):
    for col in range (0, 21):
    
        #eval(f)
    
        #if f == y:
        #   print ("o", end="")
        if row == 10 and col == 10:
            print ("+", end="")
        elif row == 10:
            print ("-", end="")
        elif col == 10:
            print ("|", end="")
        else:
            print (" ", end="")
    print()
```

My code produces the following, which isn't a bad start:

```
          |       
          |      
          |    
          |    
          |   
          |  
          |  
          | 
          |
          |
----------+----------
          |
          |
          |
          |
          |
          |
          |
          |
          |
          |
```

But now I'm stuck... My question is: how do I draw a given function within my axes?

This is the main idea I have:

- I need to replace white space/axes with `'o'` where the given function should be plotted

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: You can pass a function as a parameter to method which performs the function for x = -10 to 10, rounds the results to integers and returns a list of results, you'll then have a list of y values which you can plot

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to skin this cat. The most compact would probably be doing a function reversal (getting all f(x) and then do procedural drawing of the lines corresponding to the results or empty grid lines) but it would be the least flexible and you'll be able to plot only linear functions. The procedural way you're attempting is also extremely inefficient as demonstrated in TMrtSmith's answer.

It's probably a better form to just split your grid creation and plotting to separate procedures - this can also be done on a number of ways but the following one will give you the ability to not rely on STDOUT. Generating the grid is quite simple:

```
grid = []  # we'll use a list to store the individual rows
for y in range(-10, 11):
    if y != 0:
        grid.append("|".center(21))
    else:
        grid.append("+".center(21, "-"))
```

Now all you need is to plot your function on top of this grid by replacing the characters on each matching grid line:

```
for x in range(-10, 11):
    value = int(f(x))  # get the function result as int, you can call any other function of course
    if -10 <= value <= 10:  # no reason to plot outside of our grid range
        x = x + 10  # normalize x to the grid
        y = 10 - value  # normalize y to the grid
        grid_line = grid[y]
        grid[y] = grid_line[:x] + "o" + grid_line[x+1:]
```

And then all that's left is to print the grid if you want to show it in the console:

```
for row in grid:
    print(grid)
```

Or if you want to keep it as a string you can add new lines to the grid and then print it, save it, send it, do whatever you want with it:

```
baked_grid = "\n".join(grid)
print(baked_grid)
```

It won't only plot linear functions like:

```
def f(x):
    return x + 2
```

Resulting in:

```
          |       o  
          |      o   
          |     o    
          |    o     
          |   o      
          |  o       
          | o        
          |o         
          o          
         o|          
--------o-+----------
       o  |          
      o   |          
     o    |          
    o     |          
   o      |          
  o       |          
 o        |          
o         |          
          |          
          |
```

But will also work with non-linear functions, for example:

```
import math

def f(x):
    return math.sqrt(abs(10 - x * x)) - 5
```

Results in:

```
          |          
          |          
          |          
          |          
          |          
          |          
o         |         o
 o        |        o 
  o       |       o  
   o      |      o   
----o-----+-----o----
     o    o    o     
      o oo|oo o      
          |          
       o  |  o       
          |          
          |          
          |          
          |          
          |          
          |
```

And as a bonus it will work with Python 2.6+ as well, although I'd suggest you use `xrange` instead of `range` in that case for maximum efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

Define your function first, then include the o points in the plotting loop.

```
def f(x):
    return 2*x

for row in range (0, 21):
    for col in range (0, 21):


        if row == -f(col-10) + 10:
            print ("o", end="")
        elif row == 10 and col == 10:
            print ("+", end="")
        elif row == 10:
            print ("-", end="")
        elif col == 10:
            print ("|", end="")
        else:
            print (" ", end="")


    print()
```

This works for linear functions - because you're defining the axes from the top left, instead of the center, you may need to adjust the transformation to get other graphs to plot correctly.

Comment: Your `if` block indentation is messed up. Also, this is horribly inefficient way to plot the data - you're calling `f(x)` for every point on the chart just to be sure if the current point should print `o` or some other character.

Comment: Fixed the if block.

Comment: @zwer OP is asking for help with his function, which is what I answered. In this case it's only one more check than he's already doing.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the responses, they were helpful to me. I managed to complete the program with the following code:

```
import math

function = input("Enter a function f(x):\n")

for y in range (10, -11, -1):
    for x in range (-10, 11):
        f = round(eval(function))
        if x == 0 and y == 0 and y != f:
            print ("+", end="")
        elif y == 0 and y != f:
            print ("-", end="")
        elif x == 0 and y != f:
            print ("|", end="")
        elif y == f:
            print ("o", end="")
        else:
            print (" ", end="")
    print()
```

I added another `elif` statement to print `o` where the function `f` is equal to `y`. I also ensured the axes would not override the graph by using `y != x` in the `if` statements.

I changed the variables `col` and `row` to `x` and `y` respectively (thanks @zwer). I also redefined my graph from the centre instead of the top left so it would work for non-linear functions (thanks @TMrtSmith).

I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way to have done this, but it works. @zwer, I was not able to get your code to work (I think it is a bit beyond my current skill level) but it was helpful nonetheless.

Entering `x**2` returns:

```
          |          
       o  |  o       
          |          
          |          
          |          
          |          
        o | o        
          |          
          |          
         o|o         
----------o----------
          |          
          |          
          |          
          |          
          |          
          |          
          |          
          |          
          |          
          |
```

Problem solved! Thanks!